# Export MySQL to Unicode txt File

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, export

I am currently able to export my MySQL query to a tab delimited text file, however it is saving with a UTF8 encoding. A requirement of this project is that it saves as a Unicode-16LE text file.

My current function looks something like this:

```
$select = "SELECT -removed-";
$export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
  $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($export)) {
  $line = '';
  foreach ($row as $value) {
    if ((!isset($value)) || ($value == "")) {
      $value = "\t";
    } else {
      $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
      $value = '' . $value . '' . "\t";
    }
    $line .= $value;
  }
  $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}

$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_file.txt");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the way you create $data that matters more than the headers, show us that

Comment: Have you tried converting the output to UTF-16LE?

Comment: you can convert $data to UTF-16LE with `iconv()`

Comment: Thank you for comments, also updated to display my full file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP headers are fairly irrelevant when you are creating a file from database info. Since your app is currently using UTF-8, you have two choices:

1. Fetch the information directly in UTF-16, i.e., run `SET NAMES somethingelse` instead of `SET NAMES utf8`, where *somethingelse* is your target encoding. You can fetch available encodings with `SHOW CHARSET`.
2. Fetch the information in UTF-8 and convert it to Unicode-16LE before saving it to file. You can use [iconv()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [mb_convert_encoding()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).